# Can you format an int to have characters before it?

Tags: c#, formatting

I'm using a key value to identify quotes in a sales app written in c# using MVC Core 6.  I'd like to pad the key value with zeros (which I know how to do) but also have it display with a two letter code ahead of it.  Can this be done with formatting?  I'm using EntityFramework, so I want it to display like that automatically.

For example, 1 would look like QU000001, and 200 would look like QU000200.

Thanks.

Comment: "an int to have characters before it" we call it a string. E.g. using `var myString = "MyString" + 3`.

Comment: How is entity-framework-core related? Please be clear on that because this is typically the kind of question that will keep attracting answers for ages, non of which take into account that EF is involved. (It's already happening)

Comment: BTW, the most concise way is `$"QU{number:000000}"`, but EF will only support it in the final `Select` of a LINQ statement. I won't post this as an answer before knowing how EF is involved.

Answer (score 3):

You can using a left-padding to add leading zeros to your number, so that you allways get a 6-digit string:

```
var myString = "QU" + myNumber.ToString().PadLeft(6, '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Substring

```
string Base = "QU000000";
int Value = 200;
int LengthBase = Base.Length;
int LengthValue = Value.ToString().Length;

string _result = Base.Substring(0, LengthBase - LengthValue) + Value.ToString();

//Result:QU000200
```